# What xml schema context is generated the method signature like "JAXBElemet<Xyz> createXyz(Xyz xyz)" of ObjectFactory by xjc?

Tags: java, jaxb, objectfactory

I noticed the the simpleType or complexType is defined and the types are used in the declarations of multiple element in a schema file, the simpleType or complexType is generated a method signature as "JAXBElemet createXyz(Xyz xyz)". But I'm not sure if it is root reason.

Answer (score 1):

In order to marshal an object to XML, JAXB needs to know the name of the XML element to be used. It gets this either from (a) the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the class, or (b) by wrapping the object in a `JAXBElement`, which contains the element name.

If XJC generates a class without `@XmlRootElement`, then the factory methods for that class in `ObjectFactory` will instead use `JAXBElement` wrappers, to provide the required marshalling information.

You may then ask why XJC decides to generate `@XmlRootElement` for some classes but not others, but that's been asked on SO before, so go and have a look around for that one.